# Always continue in Lisp repl

Tags: warnings, common-lisp, read-eval-print-loop, clisp

I'm running a Common Lisp implementation called CLISP. I'd like to always continue when I hit a continuable ERROR, is there a variable I can set for this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Pass the [-on-error](http://clisp.org/impnotes/clisp.html#opt-on-error) command line option.
2. Set a [global handler](http://clisp.org/impnotes/restarts.html#global-handler).

You now owe me [1 zorkmid](http://clisp.org/impnotes/faq.html#faq-fine) :-).

Comment: there is a "what are the command line arguments?" Q in the FAQ, you could charge 10 zorkmids.